# Print a vector using iterator c++

Tags: c++, iterator

I want to print a vector using an iterator:

```
#include <vector>
#include <istream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

typedef vector<int> board;
typedef vector<int> moves;


int sizeb;
board start;
moves nmoves;
istringstream stin;


board readIn(std :: istream& in ) {
    int val;
    while (in >> val)
    start.push_back(val);

    sizeb = start[0];
    return start;
}


void printboard(board n) {
    int sizem = sizeb*sizeb;
    int i = 1;

    for (vector<int>::iterator it = start.begin() ; it != start.end(); ++it) {
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeb; ++j)
            cout <<  "\t" << it;
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

And I receive this error:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression
  ('basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >' and
  'vector<int>::iterator' (aka '__wrap_iter<pointer>'))
                    cout <<  "\t" << it;
```

Could you help me?

I think I'm converting a string that I receive in a int type. Maybe I'm not using on the right way the iterator (I think that's the problem, but I don't really know)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code and error message doesn't seem matched. Check for typo.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please **[edit]** your question with a [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: I want to print a int vector and I'm using a int iterator.

Comment: Where's the definitions for `sizeb`, `start`, and `board`?  I can't compile this.

Comment: I'll edit to post the full code.

Comment: The code that you just posted - compile without issues. What is the problem, again?

Comment: This code still isn't the same as the error.

Comment: Still not getting the error you described.

Comment: And now, in your latest edit, you manually induced the error, which was fixed in the initial post. (cout <<  "\t" << *it; instead of cout <<  "\t" << it;). Why post the question, when you have fixed the issue before doing so?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to print the `int`s in the vector, I guess you want to use :

```
for (vector<int>::iterator it = start.begin() ; it != start.end(); ++it)
    cout << "\t" << *it;
```

Notice I use `*` to change the iterator `it` into the value it's currently iterating over.  I didn't understand what you tried to do with the loop over `j`, so I discarded it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The j loop is to print, for example, on a 3*3 vector, in 3 rows and 3 columns.

Comment: Your code is full of logical errors.  You vectors is 1D, not 2D.  While it can be used to hold 2D arrays, this needs some index computations I see nowhere.  Your nested loop writes the elements of the vector, but each element is written `sizeb` times rather than once.  Which is certainly _not_ what you want.  Returning `start` returns a copy of the global vector, which is also certainly _not_ what you want to do.  Using the first element of the vector as the length is also probably _not_ what you intend especially if you allow to enter an arbitrary number of ints in that vector.

Answer (score 1):

In your updated code you have

```
cout <<  "\t" << it;
```

You are not dereferecing `it` and there is no function to output a `vector<int>::iterator` so you are getting a compiler error.  Changing you code to

```
cout <<  "\t" << *it;
```

Should fix it.

As a side what is the nested for loop for?

Comment: Thanks for your help. The j loop is to print, for example, on a 3*3 vector, in 3 rows and 3 columns.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use

```
for (vector<int>::iterator it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); it++)
{
    int a = *it;

    cout << a << " ";
}
```

something like this

Comment: What does this add compared to the accepted answer?